# birt:add datasource but the eclipse not responding

Tags: sql-server, eclipse, datasource, birt

I'm trying to create a new datasource using SqlServer JDBC driver(sqljdbc4.jar) with the following credentials

```
Driver class : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver (v3.0)
Database URL : jdbc:sqlserver://xx.xx.xx.xx:1433;DatabaseName=xxx;
```

But when I'm clicking "Test Connection..." button to test the connection, the entire BIRT eclipse is not responding for a long time. Also the same credentials are successfully creating datasource in Navicat tools.

Let me know if you need any more information.Please help me,thanks~!

Answer (score 1):

This means that Eclipse is not able to establish the connection to the Database, you have to make sure to have loaded the jar driver file in Eclipse related to SQL Server and make sure to have **enabled TCP/IP connections** and **SQL Browser** on your SQL Server installation .

In addition to this: *are you sure that the JDBC URL is correct ? Are you trying to access a Named instance ?*

If you have a named instance the URL should look like the following :

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;instanceName=instance1;DatabaseName=xxx;
```